# What is the correct way to manipulate RxJS streams and publish an Observable of the results?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have a websocket connection that is generating internal message events with a ReplaySubect.  I process these events and add a delay to certain messages.  Internally I use publish().refCount() twice, once on the internal ReplaySubject and again on the published output stream.

Should the internal subject have both 'publish' and 'refCount' called on it?  I use 'publish' because I have multiple subscribers but I'm not entirely sure when to use 'refCount'.

Is it okay to just dispose of the internal subject?  Will that clean up everything else?

Whoever subscribes to 'eventStream' should get the latest revision but the connection shouldn't wait for any subscribers

Example code:

```
function Connection(...) {

    var messageSubject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(1);
    var messageStream = messageSubject.publish().refCount();


    // please ignore that we're not using rxdom's websocket.
    var ws = new WebSocket(...);
    ws.onmessage = function(messageEvent) {
      var message = JSON.parse(messageEvent.data);
      messageSubject.onNext(message);
    }
    ws.onclose = function(closeEvent) {
      messageSubject.dispose();  // is this all I need to dispose?
    }


    var immediateRevisions = messageStream
        .filter((e) => e[0] === "immediate")
        .map((e) => ["revision", e[1]]);
    var delayedRevisions = messageStream
        .filter((e) => e[0] === "delayed")
        .map((e) => ["revision", e[1]]).delay(1000);
    var eventStream = Rx.Observable.merge(immediateRevisions, delayedRevisions).publish().refCount();

    Object.defineProperties(this, {
      "eventStream": { get: function() { return eventStream; }},
    });

}


// using the eventStream
var cxn = new Connection(...)
cxn.eventStream.subscribe((e) => {
    if (e[0] === "revision") {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

publish and refCounting is basically what `shareReplay` does in RxJS4. Honestly though, you should just let your observable be "warm" and then use a ReplaySubject as a subscriber if you really want to guarantee that the last message gets pushed to new subscribers even if subscription count falls below one. e.g:

```
const wsStream = Observable.create(observer => {
  ws.onmessage = message => observer.next(message);
  ws.onclose = () => observer.complete();
});

const latestWsMessages = new ReplaySubject(1);
wsStream.subscribe(latestWsMessages);
```

Make sure you review how Observables work: after creating an observable, normally, each subscriber will call the subscription (cold), but in this case, you probably want a hot observable so that you have multiple subscribers sharing a subscription. See [Andre's video here](https://egghead.io/lessons/rxjs-demystifying-cold-and-hot-observables-in-rxjs) and the [RxJS docs on creating observables](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/creating.md) for some more info.

Also, as useful as classes can be, looks like in this case you just want a function of `makeWebsocketObservable(WebsocketConfig): Observable<WebsocketEvent>`

Comment: This is a good answer but I recommend expanding on what 'shareReplay' does(did?) and possibly on dispose. I basically need a bit of guidance on joining and sharing streams. I'll review your links!  Thanks!